# Throw new Exception In @ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring

I need to deal with an `SqlException` to prevent its information from being obtained by the front end. So I used `@ControllerAdvice` to handle global exception, and I wanted to throw a new business exception after catch the `SQLException`.

But I get this `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error.

Can I throw new abnormalities in `@ControllerAdvice` or what do I need to modify?

**This is my code:**

```
@Log4j2
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalSQLExceptionHandler {

    /**
     * 处理SQL异常
     */
    @ExceptionHandler(value = SQLException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public void sqlExceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest req, SQLException e){
        log.error("发生数据库异常！原因是：{}",e.getMessage());
        throw new ServiceException("数据库操作发生异常");
    }
}
```

I hope to catch `SQLException` and then throw a business exception. Not in one or two places, in many places need it. So try...catch... can't.

this is Stacktrace,I hidden some local bag paths and some stacks of the same rear:

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy205
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.*.core.log.publisher.ErrorLogPublisher.getLoggableFromException(ErrorLogPublisher.java:73)
    at com.*.core.log.publisher.ErrorLogPublisher.publishEvent(ErrorLogPublisher.java:42)
    at com.*.core.log.error.CoreErrorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(CoreErrorAttributes.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.AbstractErrorController.getErrorAttributes(AbstractErrorController.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(BasicErrorController.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.service.IService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f8525d18
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.*.core.log.publisher.ErrorLogPublisher.getLoggableFromException(ErrorLogPublisher.java:73)
    at com.*.core.log.publisher.ErrorLogPublisher.publishEvent(ErrorLogPublisher.java:42)
    at com.*.core.log.error.CoreErrorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(CoreErrorAttributes.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.AbstractErrorController.getErrorAttributes(AbstractErrorController.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(BasicErrorController.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    ········································
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.*.*.*.service.impl.TSdDemandServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1c133c5c
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.*.core.log.publisher.ErrorLogPublisher.getLoggableFromException(ErrorLogPublisher.java:73)
    at com.*.core.log.publisher.ErrorLogPublisher.publishEvent(ErrorLogPublisher.java:42)
    at com.*.core.log.error.CoreErrorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(CoreErrorAttributes.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.AbstractErrorController.getErrorAttributes(AbstractErrorController.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(BasicErrorController.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    ················································
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.*.*.*.service.impl.SdDemandServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2c057f7
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.*.core.log.publisher.ErrorLogPublisher.getLoggableFromException(ErrorLogPublisher.java:73)
    at com.*.core.log.publisher.ErrorLogPublisher.publishEvent(ErrorLogPublisher.java:42)
    at com.*.core.log.error.CoreErrorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(CoreErrorAttributes.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.AbstractErrorController.getErrorAttributes(AbstractErrorController.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(BasicErrorController.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    ······················································
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.*.*.*.service.impl.SdDemandServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a81b250c
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.*.core.log.publisher.ErrorLogPublisher.getLoggableFromException(ErrorLogPublisher.java:73)
    at com.*.core.log.publisher.ErrorLogPublisher.publishEvent(ErrorLogPublisher.java:42)
    at com.*.core.log.error.CoreErrorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(CoreErrorAttributes.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.AbstractErrorController.getErrorAttributes(AbstractErrorController.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(BasicErrorController.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    ·············································
```

Comment: Stacktrace? What class isn’t found?

Comment: You can, your issue has nothing to do with the ControllerAdvice. A ClassNotFound usually indicates some kind of dependency problem.

Comment: Some business class, I will add stack

Comment: But, it only appears when I do this.

Answer (score -1):

The `@ExceptionHandler` should not throw another exception because that exception is caught by Spring and interpreted as an error in the ExceptionHandler, so the handler is ignored.

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers):

> If an exception occurs during request mapping or is thrown from a request handler such as an @Controller, the DispatcherServlet delegates to a chain of HandlerExceptionResolver beans to resolve the exception and provide alternative handling, which typically is an error response.

The actual try-catch when resolving and executing the exception handler done by `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver`  can be seen [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/7c37f4bc5112d3f6cbb77a02c96b427f032d656c/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java#L415)

Instead the `@ExceptionHandler` should return one of the values referenced in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler-return-values)

Comment: The quote talks about request handler, not exception handler. Did you verify this yourself?

Comment: If I can't do this, how can I  throwing a new Exception after catch a global Exception.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I tested it with this running a sample app https://gist.github.com/Spalaiokostas/ad9a049d8ab42fc436da1c495dbc8a05
and got the following stack trace:  https://pastebin.com/gz2KE5hK

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code or the stacktrace, it is just as I’d expect. What did you mean by “the handler is ignored” in your answer? What handler is ignored?

Comment: I think the `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` logs the warning the stack trace of the exception that occurred inside the handler ie `RuntimeException`.

But the actual exception that was raised while processing the request is the `IllegalStateException` as seen by the logs:
`2023-07-06T14:11:41.159+03:00 ERROR 42185 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException] with root cause
`

Comment: Your experiment doesn’t prove what you said. Nothing says you can’t throw an exception in an exception handler, and if you do, nothing bad happens, things work just as expected.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar  So what did I do wrong, if it can throw a new Exception in ControllerAdvice?

Comment: @user22178078 `ClassNotFoundException` has absolutely nothing to do with `ControllerAdvice`. You'll need to debug your runtime classpath.

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar I have tried, and i found this exception throw when i throw a new ServiceException(my  custome exception and extend RuntimeException) , then I continue to track down, It seems to be thrown out when constructing HTTP return state(org.apache.catalina.core.forward). Finally, it It guides me to the interface javax.servlet.Servlet.service, then I can't find its implementation.

Comment: Or when building a stack? i cannot find why does it need to find my business class.

Comment: sorry, I have a mistake. I found this ClassNotFoundException be throwen because log printing stack information.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of throw new exeption, just return usefull data. Ex:

```
Error{      

Integer errorCode;      

String message;

}
```